# How to find $I=\int_{-4}^4\int_{-3}^3 \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x_1-x_2+x_3{-}x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4} \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3 \, dx_4$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I find this integral $$I=\int_{-4}^4\int_{-3}^3 \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x_1-x_2+x_3{-}x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4} \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3 \, dx_4$$

Comment: Maple says undefined, calculating it numerically. Have you tried a change of variables $$u=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4, v=x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4, w=x_3,z=x_4?$$

Comment: **Hint:** $I=a\ln2+b\ln3+c\ln5$.

Comment: Mathematica outputs $$28 i \pi + 1536 \log2 - 144 \log3 -2000/5 \log5$$

Comment: Have you tried $y_1=x_1+x_2$, $y2_=x_3+x_4$, $y_3=x_1-x_2$, $y_4=x_3-x_4$?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that it converges? You have non-isolated singularities in the domain (the entirety of the plane $x_1=-x_2, x_3=-x_4$) so at best you can look at PVs.

Comment: First thing first, where did you get this?

Comment: @user64494 the imaginary output you get cleary indicates that a pricnicpal value description is needed. the integral should be real

Comment: @tired: Could you give a reference to the definition of PV  in the multidimensional case of an unbounded integrand?

Comment: I think using the change of coordiantes you suggested, it will turn out to be a usual principal value.

Comment: @tired: I will be wating for a serious reply.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't resist as if your limits were same for each variable say varying $a$ to $b$, for any $a$ and $b$ , the following trick I saw somewhere, is applicable, but in your case, there is no short cut, I guess.

$$I=\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \frac{x_1-x_2+x_3{-}x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 =  \int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \frac{-x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4=\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \frac{x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 =  \int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \frac{-x_1+x_2{-}x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4=\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{-a}^a \frac{x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 =  \int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \int_{a}^b \frac{-x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4$$

Adding them all gives $6I=0 \implies I=0$

**P.S-** I know it doesn't answer your question, but it was too big/clumsy for a comment.

Comment: How about the convergence of the integrals? The above is in Euler's style.

Comment: I never worry about convergence until a singularity hits me on the head.

Comment: @marty cohen: Then all that is built on sand.

Comment: Ah, but take that sand, add water, and it turns into mud. Form that mud into blocks, let it dry in the sun, and it turns into bricks which can then be used to construct a magnificent building.